# Why same id() for two distinct variables with the same float value in Python 3.6.x/ 2.7.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Try:

```
f1 = 2.0
f2 = 2.0
print (id(f1), id(f2), id(f1) == id(f2))
f1 = 2.0
f2 = 2.00
print (id(f1), id(f2), id(f1) == id(f2))
f1 = 2.0
f2 = 2.0 + 0
print (id(f1), id(f2), id(f1) == id(f2))
```

Result Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32:

```
28901952 28901952 True
28901952 28901952 True
28901952 28903248 False
```

Result Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]:

```
408502020664 408502020664 True
408502020664 408502020664 True
408502020664 408502019104 False
```

Result ('2.7.13 (default, Jun 26 2017, 10:20:05) \n[GCC 7.1.1 20170622 (Red Hat 7.1.1-3)]', sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0)):

```
(140026865510064, 140026865510064, True)
(140026865510064, 140026865510064, True)
(140026865510064, 140026865509968, False)
```

Why are ids from floats identical? 
What happens behind the scenes (something like preserved integer objects in range -5 to 256?)?

Comment: Have you looked at the bytecode? I would guess 2.0 becomes a float constant and then all hardcoded 2.0 refer to that. You could try asking for user input and entering 2.0, then I'd wager they're different ids.

Comment: This is clearly implementation dependant, I get `False` for all 3 with Py 2 and Py 3 on my machine

Comment: @Coldspeed not exactly a dupe, if they are asking about the implementation details

Comment: so it's tagged with python3

Comment: and it is no dup.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to indicate which precise Python version on which precise platform you are using? I too get False on Python 3.5.1 (Homebrew) and the system-supplied Python 2.7.11 on MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: okay done - its python 3 - see Tag

Comment: Tested in Python 3.6.2 on Win32 and Python 3.6.1 Win64/ARM

Comment: *Now* it's a duplicate.

Comment: sorry, no reuse memory positions: two float vars, same value and same id at the same time - No Duplicate

Comment: Anybody who can reproduce?

Comment: Execute Python Online (Python v2.7.13

Comment: simply put it in codingground : Execute Python Online (Python v2.7.13) shows same results

Comment: see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=1I2Gi9kv0cq4ePt30nJOvN-D-UgdLmUAf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens if the code is compiled/translated into bytecode, and not interpreted in a REPL (although some interpreter *my* also show this behavior). Consider the following function:

```
def fn():
    f1 = 2.0
    f2 = 2.0
    return f1, f2
```

When this function gets compiled into bytecode, the literal `2.0` becomes a local constant of the function `fn`. Python is smart enough to see that the first `2.0` is the same as the second `2.0` so it gets stored only once. At runtime, the function will load the constant from the function's `co_consts` and store it in `f1` and `f2` respectively. This is why `f1` and `f2` have the same `id`: They are references to the same constant.

```
>>> f1, f2 = fn()
>>> f1 is fn.__code__.co_consts[1]
True
>>> f2 is fn.__code__.co_consts[1]
True
```

`2.0 + 0` does not have the same `id` because the original constant `2.0` is immutable and Python does not just skip the (otherwise idempotent) addition. The result of the addition, therefore, has to be a new object, hence a different `id`.